# context.openFileOutput() vs file.createNewFile()?

Tags: android

I have placed all of the data for my app in directories and subdirectories on the SD card, using the File object and various FileReaders/Writers and BufferedReaders/Writers.

It occurred to me that not all devices will have SD cards, so I now have 4 questions.

1. does anyone know off hand roughly what percentage of handsets running android currently don't implement SD cards?
2. is there a way I can give myself permission to manipulate the file structure of the phones internal memory (application directory) in the same why I can on the SD card?

   - or -
3. will I have to re-implement all of my code in order to duplicate the SD card file behavior in my app using openFileOutput() instead of createNewFile() ?
4. why the difference in file access for SD vs application directories in the first place ?

Comment: Why not just store your DATA in a DATAbase like SQLite?

Comment: My app data is in the form of text files so that the user can easily download/upload and edit the files directly from other devices. It sounds like I may use a database to store the non abstract data in internal memory though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)does anyone know off hand roughly what percentage of handsets running android currently don't implement SD cards?

Even if handset **can** support SD card, it does not mean it **does** support it at a given moment of time, because SD card can be removed or mounted for PC access or there are hundreds of other reasons. So, don't put anything important there.

> 2)is there a way I can give myself permission to manipulate the file structure of the phones internal memory (application directory) in the same why I can on the SD card?

Internal memory files cannot have any hierarchical structure, `openFileOutput()` gives you exception if your file name has a path separator inside. Besides that, there's no limit on how many files you can place in your `/data/data/com.your.app/files` directory. And you don't need any specific permissions to create/open files there.

> 3)will I have to re-implement all of my code in order to duplicate the SD card file behavior in my app using openFileOutput() instead of createNewFile()?

I would not. Basically all small and/or life-critical files of your application go into the internal memory, and all large and not-really-necessary files (images, videos?) go to the SD card. There will be no conflict, your application could flawlessly start and, if SD card is not available, complain about that.

Comment: And complain I will! Thanks for the advice lenik. Any thoughts on the 4th question though?

Comment: about the 4th question, I don't know exactly about android evolution dynamics, but I suspect the internal memory was originally designed as very private storage accessible to the particular application only, with strict limitations about data size and file naming (to simplify backups maybe?). In 2007 nobody even dreamed about having multi-gigabyte internal memory.